# What's the AS3 equivalent of the following AS2 code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2, movieclip, moviecliploader

I'm trying to translate the following AS2 code into AS3 because I have Adobe Flash CC, which doesn't, as far as I know (from research, trial and error), support AS2 code. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
onClipEvent(load) {
speed = 0;
acceleration = 0.4;
speedDecay = 0.96;
maxSpeed = 10;
backSpeed = 1;
}

onClipEvent(enterFrame) {
    if(Math.abs(speed) > 0.3) { 
        speed *= speedDecay;
    }else {
        speed = 0;
    }
    if(Key.isDown(Key.UP)) {
        if (Math.abs(speed) >= maxspeed) {
            speed += acceleration;
            }
        }
    if(Key.isDown(Key.DOWN)) {
        if(speed < 0.5) 
        speed = -2;
        else
        speed--;
    }
        if (Math.abs(speed)> 0.5) {
        if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
            _rotation -= 10;
         }
         if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
            _rotation += 10;
            }
        }
       x = Math.sin(_rotation*(Math.PI/180))*speed;
       y = Math.cos(_rotation*(Math.PI/180))*speed*-1;

       if (!_root.ground.hitTest(_x+x, _y+y, true)) {
       _x += x;
       _y += y;
       }else {
        speed -= speed*1.5;   
       }
}
```

This code goes in the Car layer of my car game.

Comment: So what's wrong with the AS3 version you tried to make? **Show the code** so we can advise. Otherwise not clear what the **specific problem** is here. The Manual (or Google) can tell you how to make an `AS3 enterFrame function` and will show `AS3 keyboard example code`

Comment: Adobe Flash CC uses AS3, not AS2, so I need to change the above AS2 code into AS3.

Comment: I know about AS2 being deprecated. The point of the site is to ask when stuck **after starting** something. A good question includes _"..so far I have made this effort towards AS3 version but I'm stuck on converting this XYZ part of the AS2 code"_

Comment: Sorry, I'm a new user. I've learned that I need to use the Keyboard, MovieClip, and the Event functions in my new code, but I don't understand how to use them to make my program work the way I want it to.

Comment: No worries. Also if the given Answer works then mark as solution by clicking the `✔` icon.

Comment: Except that, unfortunately, it didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Put this code inside your car's movieclip on frame 1:

```
var speed: Number = 0;
var acceleration: Number = 0.4;
var speedDecay: Number = 0.96;
var maxSpeed: Number = 10;
var backSpeed: Number = 1;
var pressedKeys: Object = {}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop)
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydown)
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyup)

function keydown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = true
}
function keyup(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (pressedKeys[e.keyCode]) {
        pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = false
    }
}

function loop(e: Event) {
    if (Math.abs(speed) > 0.3) {
        speed *= speedDecay;
    } else {
        speed = 0;
    }
    if (pressedKeys[Keyboard.UP]) {
        if (Math.abs(speed) >= maxSpeed) {
            speed += acceleration;
        }
    }
    if (pressedKeys[Keyboard.DOWN]) {
        if (speed < 0.5)
            speed = -2;
        else
            speed--;
    }
    if (Math.abs(speed) > 0.5) {
        if (pressedKeys[Keyboard.LEFT]) {
            this.rotation -= 10;
        }
        if (pressedKeys[Keyboard.RIGHT]) {
            this.rotation += 10;
        }
    }
    var vx: Number = Math.sin(this.rotation * (Math.PI / 180)) * speed;
    var vy: Number = Math.cos(this.rotation * (Math.PI / 180)) * speed * -1;
    if (!MovieClip(root).ground.hitTestPoint(this.x + vx, this.y + vy, true)) {
        this.x += vx;
        this.y += vy;
    } else {
        speed -= speed * 1.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: I put your code into frame 1 in my car movie clip layer. However, when I debug the movie, it plays the movie without errors, but I cannot control the car to make it move in the movie.

Comment: It should be in the movie clip itself, not the layer. At least it looks like that is what Manuel is suggesting. I don't code on the timeline so I may have misunderstood.

Comment: How do I define the variable "root"?

Comment: Its a logic fault in your code. replace "if (Math.abs(speed) >= maxSpeed)" with "if (Math.abs(speed) <= maxSpeed)"

Comment: `MovieClip(root).ground...` what is this?

Comment: Do I need to put a 'hitTest' function in my ground movieclip layer?

Comment: Do I need to put a 'hitTest' function in my ground movieclip layer?

Comment: Does your ground movieclip have the instance name "ground"?

Comment: Yes, it does have the instance name "ground".

Comment: this is really strange. I tested the the code and it worked: http://zulu1182.server4you.de/files/car.fla

Comment: I can't open your car.fla because of the Web restrictions here.